# How to make dropdown list with images and selected item also show with image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tell me how can I make a dropdown list but so that the elements are in the form of cards with an image? It is also necessary that the selected element be displayed without an arrow and with an image.

Comment: could please include what you have done so far?

Comment: I haven't done it yet. I would just like to know how to make it. Using the standard dropdownbutton widget or do you need something custom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code would do the trick. The `DropdownButton` accepts `DropdownMenuItem` as items. And each menu item is customizable with a widget. Just layout an image and the texts and here you go:

Check also the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e794cca995689cb4aef041603ced984b)

[image]

[image]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int? _value = 0;

  void _setValue(int? value) {
    setState(() {
      _value = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromRGBO(50, 47, 61, 1),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color.fromRGBO(57, 56, 69, 1),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              boxShadow: const [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black26,
                    spreadRadius: 5,
                    blurRadius: 12,
                    offset: Offset(0, 0))
              ]),
          child: DropdownButton(
            itemHeight: 124,
            icon: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            value: _value,
            underline: Container(),
            dropdownColor: const Color.fromRGBO(57, 56, 69, 1),
            onChanged: _setValue,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
            items: [
              for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    value: i,
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          child: Image(
                              image: NetworkImage(
                                  'https://source.unsplash.com/random/100x100?sig=$i&cars')),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 8),
                        Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              'Test title $i',
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(height: 16),
                            Text(
                              'Test $i',
                              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: And could you show if the data will come from the API, then how can I display them in the dropdown?

Comment: Please open another question on StackOverflow and let me know

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73637596/how-to-display-data-from-the-api-in-a-dropdown-list-and-get-the-element-that-i-s

Comment: I added a question

Answer (score 1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => new _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  var _img = new Image.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/TUCPamplona10.svg/500px-TUCPamplona10.svg.png");
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Test Drop"),),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Container (
            height: 50.0,
            child:new DropdownButton(
            items: new List.generate(10, (int index){
          return new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
            height: 100.0,
              child: new Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                _img,
                new Text("Under 10")
              ],
            ),
          ));
        }) 
        , onChanged: null),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this gif will give you better idea [Demo of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0sCV.gif)

Comment: Use single Container and then other ui want